# Repeating digits in number C++

Tags: c++

The task is to write a function which takes a number and finds the digit that is repeated most times in that number. It should print the found digit and the times it is repeated.

I had a problem with the case when two digits were repeating a same number of times.

For example with given number `788995` it should return `8 -> 2 \\ 9 -> 2`
How can I print that?

Here is the function:

```
void maxDigitInNumber (long long n)
{
    if (n < MIN || n > MAX)
    {
        cout << -1;
        return;
    }

    n = abs(n);
    int numOfDigits = (int)log10(n)+1;
    int digits[100];
    int helper[100] = {0};
    int counter = 0;
    int maxSize = 0;
    int number = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfDigits; i++)
    {
        digits[i] = n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfDigits; i++)
    {
        if(helper[i] == 0)
        {
            counter = 0;

            for(int j = i; j < numOfDigits; j++)
            {
                if(digits[j] == digits[i])
                {
                    counter++;
                    helper[j] = 1;
                }
                if(counter > maxSize)
                {
                    maxSize = counter;
                    number = digits[i];

                }
            }

        }

    }

    if (number == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfDigits; i++)
        {
            cout << digits[i] << "->" << maxSize << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << number << "->" << maxSize << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see what have you been tasked with, and your code, but it seems that you forgot to include the question.

Comment: I have a problem with the case when two digits repeating same number of times.

For example with given number `788995` it should return `8 -> 2 \\ 9 -> 2` How can I print that?

Comment: By writing code that prints it like that, what, **exactly**, is the problem?

Comment: use array of 10 size and increment their values via the indexes.

Comment: When you say repeated, do you mean the longest repeat length for that digit (e.g., 112 would score a repeat count of 2 for digit 1, but 121 would only score a repeat count of 1 for digit 1). Or do you mean the number of not necessarily consecutive digits (in which case 112 and 121 would both have a repeat count of 2 for digit 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the count for each digit before picking the max. After that you can pick the max value among all counts, and print all entries matching that max:

```
int count[10] = {0};
do {
    count[n%10]++;
    n /= 10;
} while (n != 0);
int maxCount = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    maxCount = max(maxCount, count[i]);
}
bool first = true;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    if (count[i] == maxCount) {
        if (!first) {
            cout << " \\\\ ";
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        cout << i << "->" << maxCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only 10 digits, so an histogram of the digits in the number takes up only 10 words.

```
// ....
int hist[10] = {};  // Full tally available for further analysis

int max_count = 0;  // result.
int max_digit = -1;

for (int i = 0; i <= numOfDigits; i++)
{
    int digit = n % 10;
    if (++hist[digit] > max_count)
    {
        max_count = hist[digit]; // could also be ++max_count ;)
        max_digit = digit;
    }
    n /= 10;
}
```

Here are some algorithms you can use:

```
// prints digits with a certain score:
void print_if_score_is(const int hist[10], int score)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (hist[i] == score)
            std::cout << "  digit: " << i << ", score: " << score << "\n";
}

int get_next_best_score(const int hist[10], int score)
{
    int new_max = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (hist[i] > new_max && hist[i] < score)
            new_max = i;
    return new_max;
}
```

Usage:

```
// ....

std::cout << "Digit most frequently found: \n";
print_if_score_is(hist, max_count);

std:: cout << "next in list: \n";
int next_best = get_next_best_score(hist, max_count);
print_if_score_is(hist, next_best);

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure your program like this:

- One function accepts the number to be analyzed and returns a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset). `multiset` allows multiple entries for the same key. So for the number 788995 you would end up with a multiset { 1: [5, 7], 2: [8, 9] }
- Another function analyzes the multiset and returns the numbers for the highest-ranking key in the set.

Comment: Why not use `std::map` with key being a digit and value being it's occurrency? It'd be much simpler

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything but `std::iostream` and `std::cmath`

Comment: Even arrays would do! You have just 10 digits from 0 to 9. Initialize the array to 0s. Take the number modulo 10 and increment the value in the array whose index is the remainder obtained.

Comment: Yes, you could simply remember the maximum sequence length for any digits encountered. But you should insist on using `std::array` instead of a raw C array. It's 2017, not 1987.

Comment: But, she isn't allowed to use it! :-(